# Second Subpanel

Tags: electrical, subpanel

Long time reader first time post.

I recently installed a 100 amp sub-panel from my 200 amp service to a barn on my property. It’s been a few months and now I’m finding that I actually should have installed the sub-panel in my detached garage that is near the barn. So, I’m wondering how would I go about adding a sub-panel with power coming from the sub-panel in the barn. I'm thinking 50 amps is plenty for this second sub-panel and would never run anything heavy on amps in both the barn and garage at the same time.

Can this be done? If so is the drawing correct with regards to wiring? I used a main panel in the barn so that I could have a main disconnect which would allow me shut off power in the barn. I believe it's required in a detached building.

[image]
Thanks

Comment: The sun panels should not be bonded past the main breaker…am I wrong. That would make the sketch incorrect.

Comment: @Ryan What are you talking about specifically? The diagram shows the neutral bars in the sub-panels isolated, and the ground bars attached to the metal panel boxes - everything exactly as it should be.

Answer (score 1):

looks like you have it correct 125% of 50 is 62.5 so you should use #6 wire

Comment: What's the 125% for?

Comment: 125% of your breaker is the wire size for the feed to the 2nd sub.

Comment: Says who? Where are you getting that from?

Comment: this is a feeder 215-2.-1  ,210-20A, 215.3 the over current protection device is the maximum load then add 125% to protect the wires

Comment: Both the breaker and conductors should be 100% of the noncontinuous loads, plus 125% of the continuous loads.

Comment: 210.3 states the OCPD sets the ampacity of the circuit. In Oregon if you have not used the calculation method, or measured values 125% is required, I know this board is all over the world but better safe than sorry

Comment: OP may not be in Oregon, so Oregon amendments may not be applicable.  It's best to stick to what NEC says, and let the OP worry about local amendments.